# Adding up the ability score?

Tags: dnd-5e, stealth, proficiency

D&D 5e If it says that I have a +7 to Stealth, do I add my Dexterity bonus (which is 3) plus my proficiency x 2 (which is 2x2 = 4) because of being an expert to it, or, is the + 7 just the number I add to my D20 roll when I make a stealth check?

I have added my Dex plus my proficiency to it in my game (I am a PC) and rolled a 30 to stealth (16 on D20 and +14 for stealth) which seems way too high even for a rogue at low level.

Comment: Also please include the level of your PC as well as any feats and other relevant features you may have.

Comment: It looks like he is playing 1 lvl Rogue with +3 Dex modifier.

Comment: Are you playing with a pre generated character from the Starter Set (Lost Mines of Phandelver) or did you create this character yourself?  You can find more detail on [expertise](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=29) and [ability score rolls](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=60) in the basic rules posted at WoTC's web site (free download).